# R interpolate lookup a column from a rating table

Tags: r

I have a data frame of reservoir elevations, and I need to use a lookup on a rating table (of Elevation versus Storage/Volume) that interpolates the corresponding storage value.

My input reservoir elevations (data):

```
ELEV        STOR
411.0
412.5
410.9
408.3
```

My rating table (stor_elev):

```
STOR      ELEV
2500      408.0
3000      409.0
3700      410.0
4600      411.0
5800      412.0
7100      413.0
```

Desired output (data):

```
ELEV      STOR
411.0     4600
412.5     6450
410.9     4510
408.3     2650
```

I've attempted:

```
data$STOR <- lapply(data$ELEV, function(l) approx(stor_elev$ELEV, stor_elev$STOR, xout=1))
```

However, this returns a list and not a new data frame column.

Comment: `approx` returns both `x` and `y` parts in a list - I think you want to just keep `approx(...)$y` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi just a note for the future can you provide your data using dput() as it is much easier to enter for other people. Here is the data for others reference:

```
data <- data.frame(ELEV = c(411.0,412.5,410.9,408.3))
stor_elev <- structure(list(STOR = c(2500, 3000, 3700, 4600, 5800, 7100), 
                        ELEV = c(408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Thanks r2evans for your comment - I have amended below
You just need to add which element of approx you want:

```
data$STOR <- approx(stor_elev$ELEV, stor_elev$STOR, xout=data$ELEV)$y
```

Comment: No need for `lapply`, shouldn't it work with just `approx(stor_elev$ELEV, stor_elev$STOR, xout=data$ELEV)`? (And a note back: I agree, `dput` is a preferred method, and the OP should provide it ... and since you copied the data, you might consider providing the `dput` output from your efforts to import it, thereby making this question/answer pair fully reproducible.)